# Pod Communication

Tags: kubernetes

How does the communication between two different pods happen in Kubernetes?

In my case I have two pods: *frontend* and *backend*, both have different containers.
I want my frontend pod to communicate with the backend pod but I don't want to use backend pod's IP( i.e.  hard coded).

Is it possible through services?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Is it possible through services?

Yes, [services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/) are the recommended way to handle this. Once you have your services set up for each pod (or replication controller, as is recommended), you can find the service IP via the [service environment variable](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#environment-variables), e.g. `BACKEND_SERVICE_HOST` and `BACKEND_SERVICE_PORT` for a "backend" service.

Answer (score 10):

A recommended method is with the DNS cluster add-on: http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/services/#dns

---

Example from the 'guestbook' app:

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/3574999fa34d54c47f43efd9eaff7e1c571c7910/examples/guestbook/php-redis/guestbook.php#L13

They use: `$host = 'redis-master';` as the default method for communicating with the `redis-master` pod.

Which was defined in `redis-master-service.yaml`: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/3574999fa34d54c47f43efd9eaff7e1c571c7910/examples/guestbook/redis-master-service.yaml

Comment: $host = 'redis-master'
this 'redis-master' defined from which field in the redis-master-service.yaml file?
name? label-name? or selector-name? thanks!